# Firebase cache when still online, iOS

Tags: ios, firebase

In the `iOS Firebase SDK`, if I perform a `.ChildAdded` query, for example, and then later perform the same query again, will the query perform on the local cache or will it hit the `Firebase` servers again?

Answer (score 1):

In general: the Firebase client tries to minimize the number of times it downloads data. But it also tries to minimize the amount of memory/disk space it uses.

The exact behavior depends on many things, such as whether the another listener has remained active on that location and whether you're using disk persistence.  If you have two listeners for the same (or overlapping) data, updates will only be downloaded once. But if you remove the last listener for a location, the data for that location is removed from the (memory and/or disk) cache.

Without seeing a complete piece of code, it's hard to tell what will happen in your case.

Alternatively: you can check for yourself by enabling Firebase's logging `[Firebase setLoggingEnabled:YES];`

Comment: So is keeping a .ChildAdded listener open across several data nodes a bad idea? I think I would then store the data in Core Data or some custom serialized file storage. I really don't want Firebase to be queried frequently for the same data.